# Failed running pyinstaller for universal2 arch. Some dependencies are not compatible

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

Pyinstaller can set the target arch when working with .spec files by specifying the target architecture in the .spec file via the `target_arch=` argument to EXE().

I want to set it to `universal2` to build a macho fat file for running on both Intel and arm64 macOS available architectures.

However, some of the dependancies are python system `.so` libraries built for current arch only (in my case it's arm64)

This leads to the following error when trying to build the executable:

```
    raise IncompatibleBinaryArchError(f"{display_name} is not a fat binary!")
PyInstaller.utils.osx.IncompatibleBinaryArchError:
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-310-darwin.so is not a fat binary!
```

So apparently `_struct.cpython-310-darwin.so` is built for arm64 only... Is there any way to build a FAT version of my project ?

where can I get builtin python framework that compiled as FAT ?

Is there a way to auto-download the right library compiled for the desired arch, upon demand ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

MacOS can not open `exe` extension as application. Need `dmg` format for repacking application and open it on macOS.Ьore precisely, you need utilize `py2app` command line for compile python application to macOS.

First you need install py2app.

`pip install py2applet` 

After make `setup.py` file for write to it external files which using in main python file, with command:

`py2applet --make-setup <MAIN-FILEAPPNAME.py>`
 instead of `MAIN-FILEAPPNAME.py` specify name of file which run your application.
And the last one command is 
`python setup.py py2app -A`.
 It command crete exec file and shell of application.It is main folder named `Contents` , `Frameworks` file which include Python and packages, which used in base file. `Info.plist` for display information version, data about application and exec file with python code. After successful work of py2app run application in created near `dist` folder.